# Using jQuery to load external PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using this code to load pages onclick without reloading the current page:

```
$(function() {
   $("#tabs a").click(function() {
      var page = this.hash.substr(1);
      $.get(page+".php", function(html) {
         $('#content').html(html)
      });
      return false;
   });
});
```

The code is working and everything's fine except that it looks for the pages to display within the same path of the current page, for example if the current page is `www.mysite.com/index`
It looks for `www.mysite.com/index/page.php`
and this page doesn't exist because I put my PHP pages in a specific folder
how to change the code to make it look for the external pages in the specific folder that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get`, forms, anchors, etc. will all use relative paths if you give them relative paths.  If you want them to use an absolute path, provide an absolute path.  Absolute paths begin with a slash `/`.

For example:

```
$.get("/" + page + ".php" ...
```

This of course requires `page` to be the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$('#content').html(html);` You forgot parentheses around the jQuery selector.

Comment: No it's ok in the original code it's there but still the same problem

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#tabs a").click(function() {
    var page = this.hash.substr(1);
    $.get("php/" + page + ".php", function(html) {
        $('#content').html(html);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Please take the time to check your syntax.

Comment: @Daedalus just a copy of his code + path, did I miss something?

Comment: And?  You still have an error in there.  It isn't right to give incorrect syntax in an answer, when you know the right way to do it.  If your answer contains the original question, but has errors, then fix them.

Comment: `$(#content).html(html);` should be `$('#content').html(html);`

Comment: Thanks Erik for your quick answer but it doesn't change the situation, It just added "php" to the current path

Comment: isn't that what you wanted ? You can change `php/` to any sub directory you want were you store your php files.

Comment: The current path is: www.mysite.com/user/username
The original code gives www.mysite.com/user/username/page.php
your code gave www.mysite.com/user/username/php/page.php
The desired path is www.mysite.com/php/page.php

Comment: so change `php/` to `../../php/` or whatever location you store your php files.